# How do I do this?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, attributeerror

**Attribute Error: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'
this code is giving this error**

```
   from tkinter import *
   from tkinter import messagebox
   from PIL import ImageTk
   \#from PIL import Image
   import PIL.Image
   root=Tk()
   root.geometry('300x400')
   Button(root,text='open second window',command=open).pack()
   def open():
      global myimage , img
      img=PIL.Image.open("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\test\\img_lights.jpg")
      myimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
      top=Toplevel()
      top.geometry("300x400")
   Button(top,text='close window',command=top.destroy).pack()
   Label(top,image=myimage).pack()
    mainloop()
```

**I want the image to come on top level window but it is showing attribute error**

Comment: "How do I do this" is not a very descriptive question! It does not identify the issue!

Comment: It is better to fix the indentation issue of the posted code.  The attribute error seems cannot be reproduced based on the posted code.  Also better not to use `open` as user-defined function because it is a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

I do not used `PIL`. Re-arranged your code in order to make it working.  Don't use double slash.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk 
import PIL.Image

root=Tk()
root.geometry('300x400')
 
def open():
    global myimage , img
    img=PIL.Image.open(r"C:\Users\HPDesktop\test\img_lights.jpg")
    myimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    top=Toplevel()
    top.geometry("300x400")
    Button(top,text='close window',command=top.destroy).pack()
    Label(top,image=myimage).pack()

Button(root,text='open second window',command=open).pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]